# Header/Footer ruler is not appearing in the text

Tags: header-footer

I'm writing my PhD-thesis and not getting the header-footer ruler in the chapters.

The preamble is like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

%Packages used
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Margins and Header/Footer
\usepackage[top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{--DRAFT--}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\title{}

\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\maketitle                 
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\include{dedication}       
\include{acknowlegements}   
\include{abstract}         

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{roman}   
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{conclusions}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I get the rules; not in the title page or in chapter starting pages, which is normal. Can you please state more clearly your problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The header-footer ruler/header title is not appearing in the chapter starting pages as well on the pages thereafter.

Comment: Hi mafp, I have already edited my code according to your comment.

Comment: A tip: if you want to ping someone directly (like me in your last comment), add a `@` before the name, like so: `@NKaushik`. I, too, get the the rules in the pages following the first page of a chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better shape for your document. Some points to notice:

1. The packages `a4` and `epsf` are obsolete
2. For automatic inclusion of toc and lists in the table of contents, load the package `tocbibind`
3. If you really want the rules also in the chapter starting pages, redefine the `plain` page style as shown below
4. The setting of a flexible baseline skip is better avoided; the `heightrounded` option to `\geometry` is what's needed
5. `fancyhdr` warns you to increase the value of `\headheight` (it can be done in `\geometry`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

%Packages used
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{tocbibind} % for toc and lists in toc

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  anchorcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  pdfview=FitB}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Margins and Header/Footer
\geometry{a4paper,
  top=2in,
  bottom=1.5in,
  left=1.5in,
  right=1in,
  headheight=14.5pt, % the default is too short
  heightrounded, % avoids the need of a flexible baselineskip
} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[R]{--DRAFT--}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyhead[R]{--DRAFT--}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle                 
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\include{dedication}       
\include{acknowlegements}   
\include{abstract}         

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{conclusions}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @egreg, modified my preamble as you have suggested. But, i'm getting the header ruler\heading or footruler only on the chapter starting page. I want the default fancyhdr options i.e. no header\footer on the chapter starting page, but on the rest of the following chapter pages. Another thing, is there any conflict of fancyhdr with titlesec? I want to customize my titles with titlesec.

Comment: Sorry, but I get the expected result. Without seeing how you use `titlesec` it's very difficult to say something more. Maybe you can ask a follow-up question with this code and your `titlesec` setting.

Comment: Hi @egreg i have added these lines to my code:\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{charter}